# Angular 6 Karma Testing API Issue

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to Unit testing. I have created an Angular 6 app and want to do unit testing. I am getting some errors after running `ng test`.

[image: NotificationPageComponent Error]

Notifications Page is calling the service `NotificationService.getNotifications()` which is defined in `notification.service.ts`

Notification Component Test File:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NotificationsPageComponent } from './notifications-page.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";

import { AuthService } from '../../shared/auth/auth.service';

describe('NotificationsPageComponent', () => {
  let component: NotificationsPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NotificationsPageComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [AuthService],
      declarations: [ NotificationsPageComponent ],
      imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NotificationsPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**notification.service.ts**

```
import { AppConfigService } from '../services/app-config.service';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/auth/auth.service';
....
export class NotificationService {
    ....
    getNotifications() {
        return this.http.get(this.appConfig.config.api_link + '/notes?show_on_dashboard=true', { headers: this.authService.header() })
        .pipe(map(res => JSON.stringify(res)));
    }
}
```

this `api_link` is coming from `app-config.service.ts`

**app-config.service.ts**

```
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
export class AppConfigService {
    private appConfig;
    loadAppConfig() {
        this.http.get('./environments/env_settings.json').subscribe((data) => {
            this.appConfig = data;
            console.log('Environment variables loaded from env_settings.json');
            console.log(this.appConfig);
        },
        (err) => {
            console.warn("Error loading env_settings.json, using envrionment file instead");
            this.appConfig = environment;
        });
    }

    get config() {
        return this.appConfig;
    }
}
```

I am getting 6 erros in Karma console and all are the same **TypeError: Cannot read property 'api_link' of undefined**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide AppConfigService in your test spec.